# Coded Value Domain is showing, but not Description?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, esri-geodatabase, domains

I have a Domain that is working, but the issue is when I query on the feature.  I need to be able to search on the Coded Description, not the Code Value.

The attribute table is giving me the Coded Description dropdowns, but when I try to query on any of these values, I need to use the code.

No subtypes on this feature either.

[image: Coded Domains and Attribute Query]

[image]

Comment: Field is a string.  The query displayed works just fine, but I want a user to simply query for 'CKT54', not the coded value.  The 'CKT69KV' value is working correctly.

Comment: CKT69KV works because it's not part of the domain. As for querying on the descriptions, don't know if that is possible.

Comment: CKT69KV is part of the domain, you can see it listed in the table behind the Attribute dialog.

Comment: I don't think so, or it would show as 69 - CTK69 in the Unique Values box. It appears to simply be a value in the FEEDER field. This is allowed; you can have a domain on a field and still have values which aren't in the domain. Typically you'd run a validation to flag those if you don't want them.
If you don't mind adding new fields, see http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/64389/export-to-a-shapefile-and-maintain-domain-coded-values for ideas on exporting descriptions and joining them back, leaving a new field to query on.

Comment: Just added a graphic showing CTK69KV as part of the domain.

Answer (score 1):

Posted this in comments, but got scolded for too long a discussion in comments. May get scolded for posting this in answers, but not sure where else to place it. Chat was suggested, but it's not my thread, so anyway...

Ok, point taken, but the value in the field is the string 'CKT69KV', not '69'. If it was 69, you'd see 69 - CKT69 in the Unique Values box. The Code is what is actually entered in the field. That particular record(s) has the Description entered. Either way, the link in my comment above has a workaround to do what you want.