# Exporting feature class from Geodatabase to shapefile, shortens/abbreviates field values in resultant file?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, file-geodatabase

I'm exporting feature class (File Geodatabase) to shapefile, after exporting the field values in resultant shapefile is shortening, like if a field value is Andhra Pradesh then in Feature class changed as a AP.

I think that that the field value is 10 character limitation. How we can by-pass this limitation.

How I can export feature class with all field values?

Comment: It is a limitation of the shape file format (DBASE IV actually) that fields are limited to 10 characters. You can set an alias (alternate name) in ArcCatalog but apart from that there is nothing you can do about it. Field name *Andhra Pradesh* sounds like an alias as alias names can have spaces but field names cannot. I believe the field name is actually *AP* with an alias of *Andhra Pradesh*.

Comment: I'm talking about field values not field names.

Comment: I think your field must have a Coded Value Domain on it and that your question might be a duplicate of [Export to a Shapefile and maintain Domain Coded Values](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/64389/export-to-a-shapefile-and-maintain-domain-coded-values).  You may want to investigate the [Transfer Field Domain Descriptions (Environment setting)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001w00000049000000).

Comment: I didn't get...

Comment: Field values in dbf has a limit of 255 characters if they are strings as in your case. But if "Andhra Pradesh" is changed to "AP" it can't be anything that is done automatically during the export. There must be some kind of join table in your file geodatabase.

Comment: Please edit the question to reflect your concern about **field** width and not **name** width. You should include the codepage you are using and the defined width(s) of field(s) of concern. You should also specify the version of ArcGIS and any service packs or patches which have been applied.

Comment: I'm using arcgis 10.1 and I found that my geodatabase consisting domain coded values. I'm so much confusing about domain coded values.Please explain me about domain coded values and How can  maintain these values in to shape file?

Comment: Thanks PolyGeo, I got the solution here  http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001w00000049000000